# How can I force cmake to use C++ header files in /usr/include in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake

I have a cmake project that uses a header installed in `/usr/include`, let's call it `freeglut.h`. When I use `find_package(GLUT)` I get `${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR}` pointing to `/usr/include`. All's well.

Now, I'm adding CUDA, which keeps its own copies of these and other headers in one of the paths included with `find_package(CUDA)`. Normally I would resolve this by placing `${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR}` before `${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}` in `include_directories()`. However, on Unix systems cmake, in `UnixPaths.cmake`, maintains a `list` called `CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, which contains `/usr/include` and apparently keeps cmake from emitting `-I<dir>` arguments for the compiler for the directory `/usr/include`, meaning that the compiler searches the CUDA path first, and uses the `freeglut.h` header found there.

I have tried using `list(REMOVE_ITEM ...` to remove `/usr/include` from the `CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` list, but that didn't change the compiler commands that cmake made.

I could of course start hacking around with the CUDA installation, delete the headers I don't want, or modify the `CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable, but is there a clean way to tell cmake to use the system header files first, if they exist?

Comment: @Olaf you removed the C tag, but this question is almost exactly applicable to C as well as C++.

Comment: "How can I force cmake to use C++ header ..." is quite clear. And " is almost exactly" is like " a little bit pregnant".

Comment: The hamming distance between this question and the one that applies to C is 4 characters. Remove the ++ in the title and the XX in the CMAKE_CXX... variable. Here's a test you can ask yourself: if this question were resubmitted with those two changes, would you say "wow, what a great independent question" or would you just refer the asker to (hopefully) the solution to this question? I ask that rhetorically. Obviously.

Comment: Funy enough, even if a single bit flips, if there is no redundancy, the data is useless. But there is little to win in discussing with people who think "same starting letter == (almost) same language". I recommend to add B and D tags. _These_ really have a hamming distance of 1. Btw: "C and "C++" cannot be compared: different lengths. If 0-padded, it is still much larger - binary representation. Don't start a fight you cannot win.

Comment: My only point here is that this is a problem about cmake generating a compiler command with a specific header search path order. If you check out `UnixPaths.cmake` you'll see that the same mechanism works for both C and C++ languages, and if you check out the gnu compiler suite documentation you'll see that the header file search path behavior is identical between `gcc` and `g++`. The problem is the same and one would hope the solution is the same for both languages. There is nothing in cmake that hardcodes excluded system paths for B or D or Fortran, so I didn't tag those languages.

Comment: Also, since I can see you really love to be perfectly pedantic, I think I did win this fight, because my tag is back. Will you be sending my internet points by mail, or...

Comment: I was talking ybout the hamming distance. And as you are talking about the GNU Compiler Collection: Add Ada, Objective-C to the list. However, I'll leave your pound of meat; enjoy it. Btw. my point was not to change the tags, but make question title, text and tags consistent. Apparently you did not get the hint. **`'\x04'`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87045/discussion-between-matth-and-olaf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the `-idirafter` flag should help you:

> -idirafter dir
>
> Search dir for header files, but do it after all directories specified with -I and the standard system directories have
>   been exhausted. dir is treated as a system include directory.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

You can use it like this to lower CUDA include dirs priority:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -idirafter /usr/include/<CUDA_includes>")
```